# Turtles walking through nodes in a straight line

Tags: netlogo

I am implementing different walking procedures. In one of them turtles, should move/walk through "navigational-nodes"  in a straight line toward a set of *goals* following the principle of least effort (shortest distance).

I haven't been able to program this without getting weird walking patterns ([here a netlogo file with a toy example](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/18116710/testing_01.nlogo)). The key procedures are:

```
to-report route-on-the-way-to [l current-distance]
  let routes-on-the-way-to-one-goal (nodes in-radius 3 with [distance l < current-distance  - 1])
   report min-one-of routes-on-the-way-to-one-goal [distance self]
end

to walk-towards-goal
  let last-distance distance goal
  let best-route route-on-the-way-to goal last-distance

  ifelse best-route = nobody
  [ face goal ]
  [ face best-route]
  fd 1
end

to move-walkers

    if ( one-of (nodes-on patch-here) = goal and one-of (nodes-on patch-here) != myhome) [

      ifelse random-float 1.0 < 0.8
      [ set goal myhome
       walk-towards-goal ]

       [set goal one-of potential-goals
       walk-towards-goal ]

     ]  
    if (one-of (nodes-on patch-here) = goal and one-of (nodes-on patch-here) = myhome)
    [
      set goal one-of t-potential-goals
      walk-towards-goal ]

    if (nodes-on patch-here != goal)
    [ walk-towards-goal]

end
```

With this solution, the walking *routes* change too much. Any ideas about how to do it so that walking routes are more consistent over time?

[image]

Comment: In the NetLogo Models Library, there is a model called 'Link-Walking Turtles Example' which I think does exactly what you want

Comment: Yes, it is similar to what I want. Using that solution, the question would be how to set the "road" layout ( I found a Road Network Builder file), and how turtles can **walk** through the links to get further nodes or intersections.

Comment: Have you tried making `goal` a local variable for each turtle? It seems to me that could be the problem here, since every turtle is measuring the global `goal` they could be facing wrong positions or supposing they're farer than what they are.